# Getting username when logged in with Auth0

Tags: openid-connect, openid, access-token, auth0

I'm using auth0 for my auth needs. I have username required enabled from the console for my database. When a user logs in, the profile scope response I get does not include this username. the "nickname" field returns the left hand side of my email. For example, if I signup with the email "my_email_address@gmail.com" and the username "MyCoolUserName", the nickname field will have "my_email_address" on it and there wont be a "username" field returned by auth0

My question is; how do I get the username I signed up with?

Comment: if you look inside the returned id-token, is the username included in the token itself?

Comment: it does not, unfortunately. I can see the field in the Auth0 portal for the user. I'm using these scopes "openid profile email offline_access"